# Does fsync/FlushFileBuffers wait for outstanding asynchronous IOs to finish?

Tags: linux-kernel, iocp, windows-kernel, aio, fsync

The background is developing DBMS kernel, specifically database checkpoint processing. Rules of the game are such that we need to wait for outstanding asynchronous IOs on the file to finish, before issuing fsync().

Current solution we deploy, is to count asynchronous IOs in-flight, manually, wait for this count to go own to 0, before fsyncing or FlushFileBuffer-ing. The question is whether we really have to do that, perhaps kernels/filesystems do it by themselves?

The OS in questions are Windows and Linux, mainly, although I'm also curious how BSD based OS handle that, too.

On Linux, we'e using libaio, for asynchronous IO.

Comment: you several time asynchronous call write file and then `FlushFileBuffers` ? but how you can be sure that you call `FlushFileBuffers` after all write calls ? how you select time when you call `FlushFileBuffers` ? so i think you anyway need maintain count of active file I/O and decrement it after every I/O finished, and when count became 0 - call `FlushFileBuffers` (but not wait in dedicated thread). question even not in internal implementation of `FlushFileBuffers` but you anyway need somehow call it only after all  write

Comment: well, this is how checkpointing works. Here is an more or less easy explanation https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2011/01/29/how-innodb-performs-a-checkpoint/  I know I initiated all  writes for dirty bufferpool pages up to an "LSN", e.g via IOCP, libaio, Windows threadpool IOs.  I want these writes to be persistent, not in-flight, before I write this LSN in checkpoint record. And yes, the question is about internal implementation of FlushFileBuffers. It is OS that handles IO, so I was curious.

Comment: you initiated all writes for dirty pages from single thread and then just call `FlushFileBuffers` after it ? i initially assume more complex situation when can be writes from arbitrary working threads and after it `FlushFileBuffers`. if all from single thread sequential - really question only in `FlushFileBuffers` (`CcFlushCache` )implemetation

Comment: and you use cached I/O on file ?

Comment: Unbuffered IO. Possibly multiple threads. all writes are async, so maybe it should not matter whether I initiated them from one or many threads.

Comment: how you in this case select when call `FlushFileBuffers` ? if you can begin write operations from multiple threads - possible some write even not begin before your call to `FlushFileBuffers` if you not somehow synchronize this things.. posible situation when you initiate multiple asynchronous write from the same thread (it usually return status pending) and then call `FlushFileBuffers` from this thread

Comment: also if you use *Unbuffered I/O* `FlushFileBuffers` have no effect for this. you need in this case wait all unbuffered I/O finished

Comment: FlushFileBuffers should have some effect, e.g it synchronizes the disk cache to what they call "stable media"

Answer (score 4):

On Windows: Yes, for a given `HANDLE` instance, the current asynchronous i/o queue is drained before `FlushFileBuffers()` is executed. If you are writing a database, you really ought to use `NtFlushBuffersFileEx()` instead, it offers far finer granularity of synchronisation, makes a huge difference.

On FreeBSD: Certainly with ZFS, yes. I can't say I've tested UFS, but I'd be surprised if it were not the same. FreeBSD implements cached async i/o as a kernel thread pool in any case, only uncached async i/o is truly async.

On Mac OS: No idea, and worse, disk i/o semantics have been all over the place last few releases. It was once very good, like BSD, but recently it's been downhill. Async file i/o was always nearly unusable on Mac OS in any case, the maximum 16 depth queue limit plus the requirement to use signals for async i/o completion is very hard to mix well with threaded code.

On Linux: For synchronous i/o, yes `fsync()` enforces a total ordering, per inode, if your filesystem guarantees that (all the popular ones do). For libaio, which only really works right for `O_DIRECT` i/o in any case, I believe that the block storage layer does flush all enqueued i/o before telling the device to barrier, unless you have disabled barriers. For io_uring (which you ought to be using instead of libaio), for non-`O_DIRECT` i/o, the ordering is whatever the filesystem enforces for per-inode i/o *once io_uring has processed the submission*. For io_uring with `O_DIRECT` i/o, the block storage layer is a singleton, and should enforce ordering across the whole system, *once io_uring has processed the submission*.

I keep mentioning "once io_uring has processed the submission" because io_uring works with ring buffered queues. If you add an entry to the submission queue, it will get processed in order of submission by io_uring (i.e. the queue gets drained). From the moment of submission to the moment of io_uring consuming the submission, there is no ordering. But once io_uring has consumed the submission, the destination filesystem has been told of the i/o, and whatever ordering guarantees it implements it will apply to the ordering of completions it emits back to io_uring. So, when using io_uring, do not proceed after i/o submission until io_uring has drained your i/o submission request from the submission queue. This happens naturally using the syscall to tell io_uring to drain the queue, or for polling drains, you can watch the "last drained item" offset the kernel atomically updates as it consumes submission items.

Source: I am the author of [the reference library for the WG21 C++ standardisation of low level i/o](https://ned14.github.io/llfio/). Caveat: all of the above is purely from my memory and experience, and may be bitrotted or wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Very good points. I understand, it is all from your memory, but did you ever come across any official, or semi-official, documentation about ordering?

Comment: Nothing official. There was a middle range of Windows 10s which had broken the POSIX read/write atomicity guarantees, so early Win10s and all preceding Windows were fine. When I reported it to Microsoft, they fixed it as a backwards applied critical update, and now there is a soak test run weekly to prevent that ever happening again. So there are strong unofficial guarantees on the major platforms, at least. Linux is, as usual, the most wild west of all the platforms. I believe the authors of SQLite and Postgre would agree with that assessment too.

Comment: @NiallDouglas Didn't Linux drop block barrier support back in 2.6.37 ([LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/400541/), [Kernel Newbies Changelog for 2.6.37](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_37#Block))?

Comment: @NiallDouglas How do you test this? We already test database recovery by killing and restarting the process, and we sometimes do observe that a `write()`, `pwrite()` or equivalent operation was only partially fulfilled. But, we currently cannot exercise file system recovery (or anything that would show the effects of missing `fdatasync()` or equivalent calls). I could imagine that there exist virtualization techniques that would allow simulating this without cutting power to the host system.

Comment: @MarkoMäkelä What you refer to isn't what was actually asked. The OP asked whether `fsync()` forced an ordering onto concurrent i/o from the perspective of software. This is related to, but is not equivalent in any way, to the ordering actually implemented by the hardware. And only the latter matters for sudden power loss. The difference is identical to atomic memory operations in the CPU, these create an *apparent* ordering to code on the CPU, but have little to do with what actually happens between the CPU and main memory.

Comment: @Anon When I say "barrier" in my answer above, I mean the general term of "whether software makes the hardware actually flush the changes". You can't build power loss durable databases without that operation, so it's not possible to remove it. Just change how it works (which Linux 2.6 did, they moved the i/o sequencing from the device layer to the filesystem layer, makes a large improvement as parallelism can now be much higher)

Comment: @NiallDouglas Apologies for the misinterpreation -  you are of course correct.

Comment: (Niall has sent the mail [io_uring and POSIX read-write concurrency guarantees](https://lore.kernel.org/io-uring/ff3be659-e054-88c3-7b4b-c511f679333d@nedprod.com/T/#u) the [io-uring mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#io-uring) but at the time of writing it has not received any replies...)

Comment: @Anon Actually it did, but it was offlist. I'll update my answer above.

Comment: @NiallDouglas IMO, a DBMS that claims to support Durable transactions must cover the entire stack, including all hardware in the storage layer.

I might expect `fsync()` or `fdatasync()` to actually wait for any preceding writes to be durable. In Mac OS X 10.3, `fcntl(fd, F_FULLFSYNC, NULL)` ‘replaced’ `fsync()` on internal hard drives: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/746fd9fdacc52ccc297db7703ea9288b67138167

AFAIU, hardware caches are common and there might not be a standard way to disable them. It would be great to have some common interface to control this.

Comment: @MarkoMäkelä Sure, but again, that's not what the OP was asking. If you have a bunch of reads and writes concurrently occuring to the same file, possibly across multiple processes, do they perceive torn writes? POSIX says no. But does `fsync()` block all new i/o until all existing i/o has drained out, and the sync performed? This is what the OP was asking. It's a pure software question, nothing to do with durability nor transactions. It's about *ordering*.

Comment: @NiallDouglas To me, a write is outstanding until it has been completed to durable storage, across any software or hardware layers. Database crash recovery can require that some writes never be misordered at any layer, not even in the event of operating system crashes or hardware failures. My understanding is that `fsync()` does not necessarily guarantee [cache flushing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer#Cache_flushing) on the underlying storage hardware. Do you have any insight on how to control Force Unit Access (FUA) or Native Command Queueing (NCQ) on POSIX-like systems?

Comment: @MarkoMäkela : fsync does or should guarantee cache flushing, where it exists, unless on   macOS, where the alternative fcntl is documented.  It is the only API DBMS can rely on, and there is nothing else. There is no other API for sending ATA/SCSI commands to flush caches.